# Is it possible to combine multiple cameras for improved detail?

Tags: digital, image-quality

I'm a novice to photography and I'm wondering if its possible to combine multiple cameras to get a greater level of precision?  I'm thinking that if you capture more light you should be able to improve the quality?

What is the name of this process?

Comment: Multiple cameras exposing at the same time implies multiple exposures with different perspectives -- are you talking about trying to combine these multiple outputs into a single 2-D image?

Comment: Yes into a single image from multiple cameras possibly with  different properties.

Comment: The reason why a VLA (very large array) telescope can work the way it does is that the parallax (the difference in point of view between one 'scope and the next) is negligible. For targets closer to home, cameras that are a mere 6.5cm apart (about the distance between your own pupils) have a different enough viewpoint to render a stereoscopic image for everyday things; the spatial relationships between foreground and background objects shifts quite a bit.

Comment: There are also HDR images (High dynamic range) where you combine multiple exposures

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using multiple cameras to shoot the same subject were first done on television in the 1920s. Cinerama is a widescreen process that use three film cameras and then three film projectors.

- Combining pictures into one picture is called [Compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing).
- If by precision you mean its resolution, then the process is called
  [Multi-exposure Image Noise Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superresolution#Geometrical_or_image-processing_superresolution).
- If by precision you mean its dynamic range/luminance, then the
  process is called [High Dynamic Range Imaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_dynamic_range_imaging).
- If by precision you mean freezing the subject's motion, then the
  process is called [Timeslicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_slice_photography).

By the way, taking shots of the same subject with different camera settings, by one or more cameras, is called [Bracketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing).

Comment: Sublime answer.

Comment: Did you mean to mark this community wiki and not get credit for it?

Comment: @mattdm Ooops !

Comment: If you want, you can flag it for a mod to un-wiki it.

Comment: And if by precision you mean increasing the effective aperture/resolving power, it's called [optical interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_optical_interferometry).

Answer (score 3):

What you are suggesting is very much along the lines of how radio telescope arrays work.

Overlaying multiple images from **the same** camera (be that video or still) is a well known way to reduce noise (it normalises the image) or to gather more detail in low resolution images.

To grab small areas, for example faces from CCTV, it is possible to use multiple cameras.

However I don't know what the process is called.